# Implementing scanf using read()

Tags: c, linux, system, scanf

I want to implement scanf function using read system call, but I have a problem - when you use read you have to specify how many bits it will read, and I am not sure what number to use. I have for example implemented flag `%b` for binary numbers, `%x` for hex etc, should I just use a constant amount of bits like `256`?

Comment: scanf is the antithesis of the "unix way" because it does read()ing and parsing in one indivisible operation. I always recommend fgets()/sscanf() because you know the state of the input stream regardless of whether the parse fails.

Comment: Unless you wish to internally buffer you will have to read 1 char at a time.

Answer (score 3):

You will probably have to implement a buffering layer. When you call `read()`, you get a number of bytes from the stream. From the point of view of the system, those bytes are now gone and will not be returned by a subsequent call to `read()`. The problem is, if you have a format specifier like `%d`, you can't know when you are done reading the number until you *actually* read the next non-digit byte. You'll have to store that already-read input somewhere so you can use it later, for example for a following `%s`.

Answer (score 1):

`read()`, without a layer of buffering code, will not work to implement `scanf()` as `scanf()` needs the ability to "unget" characters back to `stdin`.

Instead, `scanf()` could be implemented with `fgetc()/unget()`, but it is a great deal to implement a complete `scanf()`, no matter what route is taken.

---

[Edit]

> I have for example implemented flag %b for binary numbers ...

C23, due out soon, provides support for `"%b"`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll basically have to do your own buffering, since any number you choose may be too large in some cases (unless you choose something ridiculously small) and too small in others (for example, *lots* of whitespace), so there is no right number.